# Sort strings alphabetically with Solr

Tags: sorting, solr

### Context

I have a string field for 'title' that I want to sort alphabetically. I use Solr 4.10.2 for search and sort. Since strFields are case-sensitive by default, I am noticing that Solr is sorting my titles via ASCII sort (capital letters have priority over lowercase letters) and not alphabetically.

#### Current behavior (asc sort)

Mathematics: Introduction to Algebra

Mathematics: an introduction

#### Desire behavior (asc sort)

Mathematics: an introduction

Mathematics: Introduction to Algebra

### Code in schema.xml

```
<fieldType name="string_ci" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>

<field name="string" stored="false" type="string_ci" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
```

Even after restarting Solr, reindexing, the sort is still ASCII sort

Comment: What does the analysis page show for your field?

Comment: Unfortunately the analysis page for my solr instance is not especially helpful -- I am not sure I have it configured correctly. Typically the analysis page does not show my queries being transformed by tokenizers or filters it merely shows the query encoded as bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field must be lowercased at index time.

Remove the `type` attribute in your  definition so that it applies for both indexing and queries :

```xml
<fieldType name="string_ci" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

If you want distinct analyzers for each phase, include two `<analyzer>` definitions distinguished with the type attribute `"index"` and `"query"`.

Comment: Solid answer -- I downcased each title before indexing.